# How to place three elements next to each other using css and centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I'm pretty new to css and web development and I want to create a new pwa using react and I need a header with one I'mage on the left, a centered text in the center and another I'mage on the right of this header. So good so far, I can't successfully place them next to each other but I can't do it in a responsive way. It means, when I inspect with chrome and swap the landscape from vertical to horizontal, the text which should be in the center moves a bit to the left. I know it's my code but I don't know how to fix this issue and how to make this think responsive.

I guess the problem is in `.headerApp p`, that I do the margin left here. is there any way to display it on the center without needing any margins?

Here is my html code:

```css
.headerApp {
  background-color: #57628d;
  height: 4rem;
  border-style: solid;
}

.headerApp .backButton {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.headerApp p {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.headerApp .toProfile {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header className="headerApp">
  <img className="backButton" src={require( "../assets/back.png")} alt="back button" />
  <p>Fahrt nach</p>
  <img className="toProfile" src={require( "../assets/Profil.png")} alt="go to own profile" />
</header>
```

Comment: Try adding a codepen to reproduce better your issue. That way you will get more responses. Also, the question deosn't have anything to do with React or JavaScript. Not yet.

Comment: You might want to look into [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) to achieve this

```css
.headerApp{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<header class="headerApp">
      <img
        class="backButton"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940"
        alt="back button"
        height="40px"
        width="40px"
        
      />
      <p>Fahrt nach</p>
      <img
        class="toProfile"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940"
        alt="go to own profile"
         height="40px"
        width="40px"
      />
  </header>`
```

Using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) you can do it like this

```css
.headerApp{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header class="headerApp">
          <img
            class="backButton"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940"
            alt="back button"
            height="40px"
            width="40px"
            
          />
          <p>Fahrt nach</p>
          <img
            class="toProfile"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940"
            alt="go to own profile"
             height="40px"
            width="40px"
          />
      </header>`
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.content {
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    font-size: 45px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: sticky;
    background-image: url("bg2.jpeg");
    
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="content">
                <span>HOME</span>
                <span>ABOUT</span>
                <span>CONTACT</span>
                <span><img src="sett.jpg" height=60px; width=60px; align="right"></span>
                <span><img src="bg1.jpeg" height=60px; width=60px; align="left"></span>
            </div>
            </header>
```

You can add the header content in the center and two images one to the left and the other to the right.